# Angular Js Curl -d http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, curl

i have a problem on my angular app :

i have a Curl request that work fine in my terminal :

```
  curl -d "grant_type=password&client_id=IDXXXXXX&client_secret=SECRET&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD" https://MYINSTANCE/oauth_token.do
```

now i want to use it with angular JS.

here's what i tried :

```
var getDatas = {
  grant_type: "password",
  client_id: "ID",
  client_secret : "PASS",
  username : "USER",
  password : "PASSWORD"
}

$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://MYINSTANCE/oauth_token.do',
  data : JSON.stringify(getDatas)
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  alert("response : " + response);
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  alert("error  : " + response);
});
```

But the service returns me Error.

I'm a noob on Curl requests with angular, someone can give me some advices?

Thx a lot!

Regards

Comment: In cURL, you are making a POST request with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type, not JSON

Comment: hi sorry but i don't get it... what i'm supposed to do if i just want to send some good parameters to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JS is attempting to send a GET request with data in the body.  Your curl request is implicitly using POST when you pass data with `-d`. Also, by calling `stringify`, the data you are sending is a JSON string instead of standard POST format.  So to get your JS to match your curl request (if you're also using jQuery):

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://MYINSTANCE/oauth_token.do',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  data : $.param(getDatas)
})...
```

Without jQuery (`$.param`) you can write a generic function to turn an object into a POST data string:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("grant_type", "password");
formData.append("client_id", "ID");
...
$http({
    ...
    data: formData
})...
```

Or build the POST string directly:

```
data: "grant_type=password&client_id=" + client_id + "&secret=" ...
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the server still return me error with this configuration.

Comment: @HadrienDelphin Forgot we need to convert the data object to POST param format ourselves.  Please see my edit.

Comment: Ok now i have something strange, in the console (i use chrome inspect), the console return me à 404 error on the url i try to reach. i'm sure it's working, when i copy paste it on chrome, i have the good informations... i feel a bit lost right now...

Comment: @HadrienDelphin I made an edit to explain what to do without jQuery.